# a user has no permission into its own directories in docker container

Tags: docker

[image]

I change the uid of a user in a docker container, like this, `docker exec DOCKER_ID usermod -u 30001 admin` and `docker exec DOCKER_ID groupmod -g 30001 admin`

But from the above picture, you can see the admin user has no permission into its own directories.

Can you help me?

Comment: You mention '`id admin`', but that is not the id of the current user. What does `id -a` return?

Comment: It's the same result

Comment: Then your user has the wrong id: 2000 is not the id for admin (your screenshot indicates 30001)

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake about the command

Comment: Just for testing: `docker exec -u admin DOCKER_ID ls/gome/admin/runtime/lightttpd`: would that work?

Comment: It says "Permission denied"